# How to ignore some characters when parsing a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

I like to parse a list of log strings in Python3 via the `parse` module.

A string can look like:

```
[00:00:01.913,100] [0m<inf> main: starting v2.9.0(b2393) on Zephyr v2.6.99[0m
```

or

```
[00:00:02.789,700] [1;33m<wrn> BC127: codec config differs. set default one[0m
```

So far I defined my parser

```
myParser = parse.compile("[{}] <{}> {}: {}")
```

Of course my parser fails. I don't know how to tell the parse module that it should discard for example everything between `]` and `<`. Like `"]*<"`.
my pseudo code is

```
myParser = parse.compile("[{}]*<{}> {}: {}*")
```

Comment: Have you read about the format specification on [this page](https://pypi.org/project/parse/)?

Comment: What `parse` module? Python does have one by that name in it's standard library.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/parse/
Long time ago I was looking for a "simple" parser. There are tons in python like pyl or re, but I like to stick to my old code. In the example section is - to my knowledge - no example how to skip/discard/eatup unwanted chars

Comment: parse.compile("[{}]{}<{}> {}: {}[{}") is doing the job, but I need to discard 2 results of the parsing. Guess the parse module can handle this

Comment: Have you checked whether there is an ESC (`\x1B`) before the `[`? Those definitely look like console control sequences, and most of them can be removed with a simple regex, because the `ESC[` sequence is distinctive. The end of the control sequence is always alphabetic.

Comment: yep these are control sequences(that I like to remove via parse module)

Answer (score 0):

```
Use Regular Expression:
```

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '<@ """@$ FSDF > important information < not important >'
>>> re.sub('<[^>]+>', '', s
```

'important information'